# Cant base64 decode from mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, base64, decode

I'm currently trying to echo information from my SQL database which I had to encode in order for it to efficiently write into the table; now when I try to echo the information, WHILE decoding it, the page displays nothing, I'm not entirely sure what I'm doing wrong at this point.

```
<?php
$type = $_SESSION['SESS_ACC_TYPE'];
$login = $_SESSION['SESS_LOGIN_NAME'];
$log = base64_decode(''.$row['log'].'');
if ($type == '2') {
    $qry = "SELECT log FROM logs ";
    $result = mysqli_query($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"], $qry);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        echo ''.$log.'';
    }
}
if ($type == '1') {
    $qry = "SELECT log FROM logs WHERE login = '.$login.'";
    $result = mysqli_query($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"], $qry);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        echo ''.$log.'';
    }
} else {
    //do nothing
}
?>
```

Comment: You're decoding the row before you have a row. Move the `base64_decode()` line to inside the `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` loop.

Comment: Also, what's the point of the `''`s in `(''.$row['log'].'')`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many errors with your code:

I fixed them.

```
$type  = $_SESSION['SESS_ACC_TYPE'];
$login = $_SESSION['SESS_LOGIN_NAME'];

if ($type == '2') {
    $qry = "SELECT `log` FROM `logs`;";
}
if ($type == '1') {
    $qry = "SELECT `log` FROM `logs` WHERE `login` = '" . $login . "';";
}

$result = mysqli_query($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"], $qry);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo base64_decode($row['log']);
}
```

Comment: Life saver! Thanks for cleaning it up nicely!

Comment: You should always pay attention at what kind of quotes you use, eliminate redundant code. If you have a piece of code you need to repeat, make a function or a class. Also use the correct variables. When you fetch MySQL data use fetch array and use the numeric keys. It helps against injections.

Answer (score 0):

```
since mysql 5.6.1 there are mysql base64 decode/encode functions

select FROM_BASE64('....') ...
select TO_BASE64('....') ...
```

http://base64decode.net/mysql-from-base64